# Powershell - passing parameters to script executed via piping

Tags: powershell

I am executing a script like this:

```
Get-Content .runme.ps1 | PowerShell.exe -noprofile -
```

The reasons I am doing this: 
    - Allow execution of other scripts without worrying about the execution policy
    - Deal with errors in the script I am executing (working with -File before meant that a non zero error was not visible to the caller of my script, which in turn called another script with -File)

I would like to be able to pass parameters to the script I am executing above but can't see how I would do that.

```
# This does *not* work
Get-Content .runme.ps1 | PowerShell.exe -noprofile - -ParameterName "ParameterValue"
```

Comment: I think i read something about this yesterday that suggested the - needs to be the last parameter.

Comment: The output of Get-Content .runme.ps1 | PowerShell.exe -noprofile -ParameterName "ParameterValue" - saying "-ParameterName is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet..."

Comment: Oh right, yes, there's no such parameter. I think there may be no way to do it the way you wish and you'd need to do `PowerShell.exe -noprofile -command { & .\runme.ps1 -param1 blah -param2 etc }` instead.

Comment: Answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283997/how-to-pass-parameters-to-powershell-command-when-interpretting-script-from-stan